# Using Pro*C, how to use a C++ struct with constructor, copy constructor within EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION

Tags: c++, oracle, oracle12c, oracle-pro-c

I am using Pro*C version 12.2.0.1.0.
To use host arrays in SQL INSERT statement, I am using an array of structures as below:

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
struct XYZ {
    int adata;
    XYZ() {
        this->adata = 0;
    }
    XYZ(const XYZ& src) {
        this->adata = src.adata;
    }
    XYZ& operator =(const XYZ &src) {
        this->adata = src.adata;
        return *this;
    }
};
XYZ axyz[20];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
```

My pro*c build command is as :

```
 proc code=cpp parse=partial 'include=(<list-of-comma-separated-include-folder-names>)' xyz.pc
```

But, when I compile using Pro*C Compiler, using `code=cpp`, as in `proc code=cpp` . . . , I get error as given below:

```
Pro*C/C++: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Nov 8 05:36:56 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /app/oracle/product/12c/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg
Syntax error at line 64, column 2, file xyz.pc:
Error at line 64, column 2 in file xyz.pc
         XYZ() {
 .1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "XYZ" when expecting one of the following:
   } char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
 OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
 OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
 OCIRaw, OCIString, short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor,
 struct, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
 volatile, a typedef name,
 Syntax error at line 67, column 15, filexyz.pc
      XYZ(const XYZ& src) {
  ..............1
 PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "&" when expecting one of the following:

  , ( ) [

 Error at line 0, column 0 in file xyz.pc
 PCC-F-02102, Fatal error while doing C preprocessing
```

I need to use C++ struct with constructor and copy constructor to take care of initialization, but to get Pro*C compiler accept that?
The following declaration is being allowed, but I need to use constructors for initialization:

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
struct XYZ {
        int adata;
};
struct XYZ axyz[10];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
```

Comment: I'm no Pro*C expert, but it sure looks to me like the compiler isn't aware it should be processing C++, and expects C code.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I am using code=cpp flag using proc compiler

Comment: it would be better to use code=ansi or CODE=ANSI_C to your PROC-Flags

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28427/pc_12cpl.htm#i864), the `CODE=CPP` option tells Pro C to *generate* C++ rather than C. It says nothing about the code that *you* provide to it.

You can change the "parse" mode to `PARTIAL` to permit C++ syntax in your provided code.

> To generate C++ compatible code, the PARSE option must be either NONE or PARTIAL. If `PARSE=FULL`, the C parser runs, and it does not understand C++ constructs in your code, such as classes.

Weirdly, `PARSE=PARTIAL` is supposed to be the default when you provided `CODE=CPP`, but that doesn't seem to be working, as shown by the error:

> Fatal error while doing C preprocessing

…which should be impossible as full C preprocessing is only supposed to happen in `PARSE=FULL` mode.
It is also vaguely possible that the Pro C++ parser is broken such that it only accepts member functions in a class defined with the keyword `class`. I say this only because it's a common misconception that classes defined with the keyword `struct` cannot contain such things — you might try adjusting your code to see whether the parser authors have made this mistake.

Comment: The more I look at this the weirder it gets. I'd double-check your build command too because this _should_ work.

Comment: I've edited my qs with the build command, the build command used is:  proc code=cpp parse=partial 'include=(<list-of-comma-separated-include-folder-names>)' xyz.pc

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana To be honest then I don't know :( Consider asking their mailing list / user community

Comment: However, if I take the struct declaration outside EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION; it gets compiled, but creates problem elsewhere where I use host arrays in insert command as colon followed by the array name, i.e. as :axyz

Comment: Any clue from this writeup? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28427/pc_12cpl.htm#i980

Comment: That's the page I linked to